# Using if statement inside function in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to iterate over a given set of values where for every new value the loop begins to add number by restarting from 1. The code is given below.

```
rdt2 <- function(z){
  i = 1
  k = 1
  v = 0
  b = z[1]
  while (i <= length(z)){
    v[i] = z[i]*100 + k
    if (v[i] == b){
      k = k + 1
    }
    if (v[i] != b){
      b[i] = v[i]
      k = 1
    }
    i = i + 1
  }
  return(v)
}
```

This code throws values but not the incremented ones.
Let the z be

```
c(2150L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2152L, 2153L, 
2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2154L, 
2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2156L, 
2156L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L)
```

As you can see there are numbers with different rfrequencies. I want for each number the loop to run by that frequency to get new set of numbers.
This is intended for populating column A based on column B.
Here is the data

```
structure(list(V1 = c(2150L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 
2151L, 2152L, 2153L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 
2152L, 2152L, 2154L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 
2155L, 2155L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L), V2 = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
    V3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), V4 = c(1L, 12L, 17L, 22L, 25L, 29L, 31L, 
    6L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 18L, 19L, 24L, 23L, 2L, 4L, 
    7L, 8L, 15L, 21L, 27L, 28L, 10L, 13L, 16L, 20L, 26L, 30L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now if you see V1 the values are in accordance with the V2, meaning that same value for V1 for each unique value in V2.
Now I want to fill V3 in such a way that conditions of V2 and V4 are checked. I mean that V3 can have 215101 for V2 = 2 and V4 = 12. So, there is a loop which is controlled the number of times value in V2 occurs, but there is increment by one and loop restarts for next unique value in V2.

Comment: Do you need `ave(z, z, FUN = seq_along)` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you need but there's bound to be a better way. Can you include small example of expected output?

Comment: `b[i]` is clearly wrong, you want just `b`.

Comment: In the line `if (v[i] == b)` you're testing a unique value against a vector, that causes a lot of warnings. Did you intend `if (v[1] == b[i])`? Also: Why use a separated `if` to test `v[i] != b` instead of using an  `else`?

Comment: Let me put some data

Comment: if `V2` has 2 six times then `V3` = `215101, 215102, 215103, 215104, 215105, 215106`

Comment: a function such as `rdt2(x, y)` would help me choose v1 and v2

Comment: Here is another one-liner: `(z *100L) + unname(sequence(table(z)))`. This assumes that your data is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You have not said precisely what output you want, but I am guessing you are trying to give unique values corresponding to an input with duplicates, by multiplying by 100 and adding a counter of that duplicate value.  Perhaps you want something like this

```
rdt2a <- function(z){
  v = numeric(length(z))
  uniquez = unique(z)
  freqz = numeric(length(uniquez))
  for (i in 1:length(z)){
    n = which(uniquez == z[i])
    freqz[n] = freqz[n] + 1
    v[i] = z[i] * 100 + freqz[n]
    }
  return(v)
  }

z = c(2150L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2151L, 2152L, 2153L, 
2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2152L, 2154L, 
2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2155L, 2156L, 
2156L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L, 2156L)

rdt2a(z)

#  [1] 215001 215101 215102 215103 215104 215105 215106 215201 215301 215202
# [11] 215203 215204 215205 215206 215207 215208 215209 215401 215501 215502
# [21] 215503 215504 215505 215506 215507 215508 215601 215602 215603 215604
# [31] 215605 215606
```

Comment: In that case here's a simpler alternative: `z*100 + ave(z, z, FUN = seq_along)`

Comment: Thanks this works for me! But can you explain me how it actually works.

Comment: Ambrish Dhaka: is your comment aimed at me or @Shree with the very much shorter code of  just having `rdt2b <- function(z){z*100 + ave(z, z, FUN = seq_along)}; rdt2b(z)`

Comment: Thanks! @Henry I would highly appreciate if you could explain what `z, z` mean and also `ave` stands for.

Comment: @AmbrishDhaka See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html - `ave` applies a function (by default `mean` but here `seq_along`) to the first parameter (not actually important here, but has to be the length of `z`) grouped by the second (also `z` so group by the different values).  This then applies `seq_along` to the various values of `z` by counting each individually

Comment: How about `y <- as.integer(i + ave(i, f, FUN = seq_along))` where `i = 2150` and f is a vector of names of 6 cities (i.e., strings). Would it work? I get this error `data length is not a multiple of split variable`

Comment: @AmbrishDhaka In that code you need the vectors `i` and `f` to have the same length